# Why aren’t there pre WW2 Sefarim that delve into the roots of antisemitism?

Tags: history, jewish-books, anti-semitism

The hatred & hostility towards Jews now termed antisemitism is often known as the World’s Oldest Hatred yet I can’t think of any older Sefarim that delve deeply into the roots of this horrific phenomena. I understand that there was often severe censorship, both official & self censorship to avoid the potential damage from the Christians & Muslims inherent in discussing such a thorny subject which probably severely limited what Jewish leaders felt safe expressing which might be explanation enough but if anyone can shed further light on the reasons behind this scarcity or even better is familiar with such Sefarim it would be appreciated.

Comment: [משך חכמה ויקרא כו:מד](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9A_%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%AA%D7%99)

Comment: Netziv (late 1800s) has an essay on anti-Semitism -- it's printed in the back of the Imrei Shefer haggadah.

Comment: But most critically, there was a "boil the frog" element -- Jews had seen various pogroms come and go; a lot of them thought this would be another such thing. One rabbi candidly admitted afterwards -- "at worst, we thought it'd be like another Khmelnytsky Massare." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khmelnytsky_Uprising#Jews)

Comment: Which modern Sefarim would you list as dealing with this phenomenon?

Comment: @Chatzkel I can’t list any Sefarim per se but many Rabbi’s (off the top of my head: Aryeh Kaplan, Pinchos Winston, Avigdor Miller, Akiva Tatz, Rav Yitzchak Hutner, Rav Morgenstern’s Toras Hachachma etc) have grappled with this most noxious disease in their lectures or printed works